What's the distinction between "quantum computation" and "quantum computing"?
Is there a distinction between usage of the terms "quantum computation" and "quantum computing" or are they completely interchangeable?
For example, it is conceivable that "quantum computation" might be understood to refer to the theoretical study of computation with quantum resources (the equivalent of theoretical computer science), whereas "quantum computing" might refer to more applied contexts (similar to high-performance computing).

I recall the book by Nielsen and Chuang is titled 'quantum computation and quantum information'. From grammatical perspective, 'computation' is a noun (or a task) while, 'computing' is  verb (or, doing the task).
I have not encountered any other difference, at least in the main stream community.
